Find the Laurent series of $\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}$ at $z=-2$.
Here's the question:

Find the Laurent series of $\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}$ at $z=-2$.

Here's what I've done:
$\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}=-\frac{1}{(z+1)}+\frac{2}{(z+2)}$
We have singularities at $z=-1$ and $z=-2$ so the annulus is $
0<|z+2|<1$.
$\frac{2}{(z+2)}$ is already in the correct form.
Expanding $\frac{1}{(z+1)}$:
$\frac{1}{(z+1)}=\frac{1}{(z+2)-1}=-\frac{1}{1-(z+2)}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^n$ for $|z+2|<1$.
Hence
$\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}=-\frac{1}{(z+1)}+\frac{2}{(z+2)}= \frac{2}{(z+2)}+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^n$
This is the first way I approached the problem.
The second way I've tried to do it is the following:
$\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)}= \frac{(z+2)-2}{(z+1)(z+2)} = \frac{1}{(z+1)}-\frac{2}{(z+1)(z+2)}$
We have singularities at $z=-1$ and $z=-2$ so the annulus is $0<|z+2|<1$.
$\frac{2}{(z+2)}$ is already in the correct form.
Expanding $\frac{1}{(z+1)}$:
$\frac{1}{(z+1)}=\frac{1}{(z+2)-1}=-\frac{1}{1-(z+2)}=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^n$ for $|z+2|<1$.
$\frac{2}{(z+1)(z+2)}=\frac{2}{(z+2)}\cdot\frac{1}{(z+1)}=\frac{2}{(z+2)}(-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^n)=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^{n-1}$.
hence
$\frac{z}{(z+1)(z+2)} = \frac{1}{(z+1)}-\frac{2}{(z+1)(z+2)}= -\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^n + 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^{n-1}$.
I am wondering which of the 2 methods used, if any, are correct or even if both of these are correct.
Also, did I correctly identify the annulus? I am wondering because surely we could've also chosen the annulus to be $|z+2|>1$?
Thank you very much in advance!

You should finish simplifying the expression $-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^n + 2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^{n-1}$ if you intend to compare it with your first solution.

Hi, I am unsure of how to simplify the expression further.

Since you are asked for the Laurent series at $z=-2$, the annulus to be considered is indeed $0<|z+2|<1$. Your first method is standard but your second one is fine as well. As indicated by @jjagmath, you only need to terminate the calculation and you'll find the same result:
$$\begin{align}\frac z{(z+1)(z+2)}&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^n+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^{n-1}\\&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z+2)^n+2\left((z+2)^{-1}+\sum_{m=0}^\infty (z+2)^m\right)\\&=2(z+2)^{-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(z+2)^n.
\end{align}$$

Thank you so much I really appreciate this!
